# how to show/hide bootstrap popover on radio button value set to false

Tags: apex, jquery, bootstrap

Im listening for a change event on radio buttons. If the value is set to false I want to show the popover. Below is what I have, but the popover doesn't show.

```
            $j = jQuery.noConflict();
                $j(function(){
                    $j("input:radio[name$=mailAddress]").change(function (){
                        if($j(this).prop("checked")){
                        var radio_value= $j(this).val();
    if(radio_value==='false'){
         $j('#myForm2').popover('show');

    } else {
        $j('#myForm2').popover('hide');
    }
}
});
});



<fieldset>
 <apex:selectradio  id="mailAddress">
       <apex:selectoption itemvalue="true" itemlabel="Yes" />
      <apex:selectoption itemvalue="false" itemlabel="No" />
 </apex:selectradio>
</fieldset>




<div id="myForm2" class="hide" data-toggle="popover">
 <form action="/echo/html/" id="popForm" method="get">
 <div>                                    
   <label for="about">About Me:</label>
   <textarea rows="3" name="about" id="about" class="form-control input-md">    </textarea>
```

Save
  `enter code here`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code produces a true or false boolean that can then be used to show a popup:

```
<apex:page>
<apex:form>
     <apex:selectradio  id="mailAddress">
         <apex:selectoption itemvalue="true" itemlabel="Yes" />
         <apex:selectoption itemvalue="false" itemlabel="No" />
     </apex:selectradio>
</apex:form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($) {
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("input:radio[name$=mailAddress]").change(function() {
             var b = $(this).val() === 'true';
             console.log(b);
             // Use the boolean b to show or hide the popover
         });
     });
})(jQuery.noConflict());
</script>
</apex:page>
```

**PS**

Here is a working example including the popover logic. The technique for getting HTML into the popover I took from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128425/contain-form-within-a-bootstrap-popover#answer-12128784).

```
<apex:page>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div style="height: 100px"/>

<apex:form>
     <apex:selectradio id="mailAddress">
         <apex:selectoption itemvalue="true" itemlabel="Yes" />
         <apex:selectoption itemvalue="false" itemlabel="No" />
     </apex:selectradio>
</apex:form>

<div style="height: 100px"/>

<span>Element to put popover next to</span><a href="#" id="myPopover" data-toggle="popover"></a>

<div id="myForm" class="hide">
    <form action="/echo/html/" id="popForm" method="get">
        <div>                                    
            <label for="about">About Me:</label>
            <textarea rows="3" name="about" id="about" class="form-control input-md"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($) {
     $(document).ready(function() {
         var p = $("#myPopover");
         p.popover({ 
             html: true,
             content: function() {
                 var f = $("#myForm");
                 return f.html();
             }
         });
         $("input:radio[name$=mailAddress]").change(function() {
             var b = $(this).val() === 'true';
             p.popover(b ? 'show' : 'hide');
         });
     });
})(jQuery.noConflict());
</script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: i've tried it but popup doesn't show.

Comment: @nerdyperson Yeah that bit is awkward - see the PS.